# How to Create online radio management system with ruby on rails using icecast streaming server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, icecast, webradio

I am trying to build the online radio management system with Ruby on Rails. I am using Icecast streaming server for streaming audio. Please suggest architecture on radio management system or refer any examples that already available. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  What exactly are you trying to do and manage?  Are these servers just for your own streams?  Or are you selling?  Most places just write their own code for this.  Icecast has simple config files.

Comment: I am trying to implement audio streaming for web so that user can listen audio and some one can manage the audio library on server. It is more likely a live web radio system.

Answer (score 2):

So, if I understood correctly, you should follow the example of architecture given by Airtime, or even use airtime instead of programming a new radio manager. The documentation is here:
http://files.sourcefabric.org/manuals/Airtime/en/airtime23forbroadcasters-en-2013.04.19-15.54.00.pdf
See specially page 4, to have a reference of what you need in order to program a good manager.